# Combining two lists into a dictionary, where the values relate to individual (and often repeating) keys

Tags: list, dictionary

I've been thinking this over for a while and haven't been able to come up with a solution:
I have two lists:

- links = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3]
- speeds = [50, 35, 20, 12, 19, 16, 65, 46]

What I need to do is make a single dictionary that will combine these two as such:
dictionary = {1:[50,35,20], 2:[12,19,16], 3:[65,46]}

Note that the two lists above are examples (my actual lists are too big to fit here). But the concept is the same, both are lists of integers. However the list of links isn't necessarily in ascending order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
links = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3]
speeds = [50, 35, 20, 12, 19, 16, 65, 46]

res = {}
def add(x):
    res[x[0]] = res.get(x[0],[]) + [x[1]]

map(add, zip(links,speeds))
print res # {1: [50, 35, 20], 2: [12, 19, 16], 3: [65, 46]}
```